# Find the nodes with the most mutual connecting nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working with a data set that contains customers, their purchases and the businesses they purchased from, and I'm trying to determine which businesses share the highest number of mutual customers. Ideally the output would be a table that lists the connected businesses and the number of mutual customers. I.e.:

```
| BUSINESS_1 - BUSINESS_2 | 4 |
| BUSINESS_1 - BUSINESS_5 | 3 |
| BUSINESS_3 - BUSINESS_7 | 2 |
| BUSINESS_4 - BUSINESS_9 | 2 |
```

I don't have much at this point, but the query I'm working with looks something like this:

```
MATCH (c:Customer)<-[:Trans_Cust]-(t:Transaction)-[:Trans_Business]->(b:Business)
RETURN c, t, b
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this should do the trick, maybe provide a sample dataset on http://console.neo4j.org for us to help.

```
MATCH (b:Business)
MATCH (b)<-[:Trans_Business]-(t:Transaction)-[:Trans_Cust]->(c:Customer)
MATCH (c)<-[:Trans_Cust]-(:Transaction)-[:Trans_Business]->(other:Business)
WHERE b <> other
WITH b, other, collect(distinct(customer)) as customers
RETURN b, other, size(customers) as sharedCustomers
ORDER BY sharedCustomers DESC
```